# How to open your own github repo from github.dev

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

In the new product of Microsoft, [github.dev](https://github.dev/), you are automatically forwarded to a VSCode web IDE.  However, I am not sure if it is possible to open your own repo (hosted on github.com), work on it and push the changes. Can you help explain if this can be done and how?

I do not seem to find a straightforward tutorial on that.

Note that I was able to open a repo of mine by clicking on the blue GitHub icon in the bottom left corner, but I fail to install a terminal, because

> Terminals are not available for web editor. To use terminal you need to continue working in an environment that can run code, like codespaces or local VS Code

I read that codespaces are a paid option for github enterprise, but the way this error message is written might suggest other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Opening your repository

You can open your repository by visiting it's page on GitHub and pressing `.` to open it in [github.dev](https://github.dev). You can also use the url format `https://github.dev/<username>/<repo-name>` with the path to your repository.

###### Making Commits

While the terminal cannot be used in the editor, you can make commits using the VSCode [source control](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol) system.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that does not work for me is the `.` (I am with a Mac).